# Unable to retrieve text of an element without tags in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, mstest

I am trying to retrieve the text of an element without a tag in Selenium C# but I am unable to do it. In the attached screenshot, I want to retrieve the text **Adell Windler**. I tried using Absolute XPath, Relative Xpath as well as cssSelector but the text that is getting retrieved is **Name:** . The Xpath that I used is:

```
IWebElement UsrNameText => Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/app-user-detail/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/h5[1]"));
```

But instead of retrieving the whole "Name: Adell Windler", it is just retrieving the text **"Name:"**. I even tried the **text()** method in the XPath but it is giving an error

```
"The result of the xpath expression .... is: [object Text]. It should be an element".
```

[Screenshot of DOM Structure with web element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErJzD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is three scenarios :

1. Only name : : if you want to get "Name :" then create xpath for strong element.
2. "Name: Adell Windler" : if you need this one then create xpath of H5 element.
3. "Adell Windler" : if you need this one then create xpath of H5 and remove "Name :" from that string.

if you are facing issue then please revert on this one.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve only "Adell Windler" and I understand your point that it can be done by creating XPATH for h5 but the problem is that XPATH of h5 retrieves only the text "Name:". If I can somehow retrieve the whole "Name:Adell Windler", then removing part of the string is easy. Attaching the screenshots for h5 xpath.